# I can't understand the output of the code fragment. can some one explane it to me please?

Tags: java

```
for(int i = 10; i > 0; i--) {
        if (i > 7) 
            continue;

        while (i > 3) {
            if(i == 5)  
                break;

            System.out.println(--i);
        }
        System.out.println(i);
    }
```

The output says 
6
5
5
3
3
2
1
I am mainly confused starting from the while part.

Comment: Debug it step by step and you'll understand. :))

Comment: I would suggest to take a pen and a paper and design your code I'm sure you will arrive to the solution **Hint** continue return to the for loop

Comment: The key here is to pay attention to the continue and break statements

Comment: I know that the loop will not execute for numbers >7. But for the numbers 4,6,7 will both print statements execute?

Comment: No, because it prints out `i--` (When i = 4, it will subtract one and print 3)

Comment: The problem is that one of the print statements contains --i so it decreases i. Therefore the questions for a specific number to have "both statements execute" doesn't make much sense. The value of i changes.

Comment: let me make my question a bit brief. For example if i=4, first it will check 4>7, since it is false it will just go to the while loop and check 4>3 which is true. Next checks if(4==5) which is false, so do nothing. Now the next part is where i get confused. Will it execute the first print "--4" which is 3 and the the second print where "i" is already 3 (so that 3 will be printed twice)?

Answer (score 2):

```
for(int i = 10; i > 0; i--) {
    if (i > 7) //until the third loop this will skip the whole "for" statement, thus the for cycle starts at i = 7
        continue;

    while (i > 3) { //the first time it loops i will be 7, so the while statement will be executed;
        if(i == 5)  // i is still 7 so this is false
            break;

        System.out.println(--i); // this will autodecrement i. In this case it will subtract 1 from i first before using it once again in the code; i will be i = 7 - 1 => i = 6
    }
    System.out.println(i); 
}
```

Becasue the `while` cycle is inside the for loop, it will execute itself until the statement is false. So after `i = 7` (passing the first if statement) it will execute the while until:

- `i` becomes less than 3.
- `i` is equal to 5.

So the first time it executes :

```
while (i > 3) {
    if(i == 5)  
        break;

    System.out.println(--i); // After we subtract 1 form i (which is 7) we output 6; 
    //Then we return in the beggining of the while loop. i is 6 so "while" is executed. We subtract 1 and output 5.
}
```

Because `i` is now 5 the while loop won't be executed so we go on along the code. We reach the end of the for statement and output `i` again which after the subtraction is 5 now. Because the `for` loop ended, 1 is subtracted from `i`, making `i = 4`. The `while` block is now executed again. We subtract 1 from `i` and output it - now equal to 3. Because the 2nd condition of executing the while loop is false - it isn't executed getting us to the  `System.out.println(i);` after which we output 3. Then because the while loop is no longer executed we subtract and output `i` until the for loop's 2nd statement is false.

Answer (score 0):

Part below ensures the numbers 10-8 are skipped.

```
    if (i > 7) 
            continue;
```

This part keeps processing "i" until it reaches 3 but breaks out of "while" when it comes across 5.

```
    while (i > 3) {
            if(i == 5)
                break;

            System.out.println(--i);
        }
```

Here goes like this:

```
        i= 10,9,8 => skipped
        // *************************
        i=7          
           //inside while
              printed : 6   // due to --i in  println(--i)
              i=6
              printed : 5  // due to --i in  println(--i)
              i=5
              //breaks out while => i==5  
           printed : 5
           i=4 // due to i-- in for statement
        // ************************* 
        i=4  
           printed : 4  
           //inside while
              printed : 3 // due to --i in  println(--i)
              i=3  
              //breaks out while => i > 3
           printed : 3  
           i=2 // due to i-- in for statement
        // ************************* 
        i=2  
           printed : 2  
           i=1 // due to i-- in for statement
        // ************************* 
        i=1 
           printed : 1
```